# $\int_{a}^b f_+'(t)dt =f(b)-f(a)?$ $f(x)$ has right derivative and left derivative everywhere in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Given a function $f(x)$ which always right derivative and left derivative everywhere in the interval $[a,b]$. How about the integration $\int_{a}^b f_+'(t)dt?$ and $\int_{a}^b f_-'(t)dt?$. Are they equal to $f(b)-f(a)$?